# How to monitor VCS but not check out anything from it

Tags: git, teamcity

I'm using Teamcity to perform a build.
My requirement is as below:
1, Monitor any changes to Git Repo A. If any changes on A, trigger the build
2, Monitor any changes to Git Repo B. If any changes on B, trigger the build
3, Monitor any changes and check out artifact from SVN Repo C to working directory when build starts. If any changes on C, trigger the build

What I have done:
1, Create 3 VCS roots for A, B and C
2, Set Check out Rules for A and B with "`-:.`". I don't want to check out artifact from A and B to working directory when build starts.
3, Set build Trigger Rules with "`+:.`". I want any change to A, B or C trigger the build

However, changes to A and B won't trigger the build unless I disable the "`-:.`" Check out Rules for A and B. It's not what I want cause I don't want to download artifact from A and B when build starts.

May I know what I'm doing wrong. Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: It is usually done the other way around — repositories have hooks that notify CI of changes, then CI triggers builds. https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+hook+trigger+build Polling must die.

Answer (score 1):

In case of TeamCity checkout rules affect both changes shown in web UI and checked out files on the agent. So if you set -:. there, then no changes will be shown in builds.

Instead, you should remove checkout rules and set VCS checkout mode setting to: Do not checkout files automatically.